# pytestの`setup_class`関数の中でインスタンス変数を設定しようとすると、mypyエラーが発生します。どのように修正すればよいでしょうか？

Tags: python, mypy, pytest

## 環境

- Python 3.10.2
- pytest 7.1.2
- mypy 0.971

## 背景

以下のクラスのテストコードを作成しています。

```
import datetime
import calendar


class Month:
    def __init__(self, month: str):
        self._month = month
        dt_start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(month + "-01", "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        _, last = calendar.monthrange(dt_start_date.year, dt_start_date.month)
        dt_end_date = dt_start_date.replace(day=last)

        self._dt_start_date = dt_start_date
        self._dt_end_date = dt_end_date

    @property
    def days(self) -> int:
        return (self._dt_end_date - self._dt_start_date).days

    @property
    def start_date(self) -> str:
        return str(self._dt_start_date)

    @property
    def end_date(self) -> str:
        return str(self._dt_end_date)
```

テストコードは以下の通りです。
毎回`Month`インスタンスを生成するコードを書くのが面倒なので、`Month`インスタンスを`setup_class`関数の中でインスタンス変数に設定しました。

```
class TestMonth:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls) -> None:
        cls.month_obj = Month("2022-08")

    def test_days(self) -> None:
        self.month_obj.days == 31

    def test_start_date(self) -> None:
        self.month_obj.days == "2022-08-01"

    def test_end_date(self) -> None:
        self.month_obj.days == "2022-08-31"
```

## やりたいこと

テストコードもmypyチェックを通したいです。
しかし、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
$ mypy --strict test_month.py 
error: "Type[TestMonth]" has no attribute "month_obj"
error: "TestMonth" has no attribute "month_obj"
error: "TestMonth" has no attribute "month_obj"
error: "TestMonth" has no attribute "month_obj"
Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

`--strict`を指定しなければエラーは発生しませんが、できれば`--strict`を指定してmypyを実行したいです。

## 質問

mypyチェックを通すには、テストコードをどのように変更するのがよいでしょうか？
そもそもクラスメソッドである`setup_class`関数の中で、`TestMonth`のインスタンス変数を設定してはいけないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

次のように `month_obj` の宣言を追加すればmypyを通せるのではないでしょうか。

```py
class TestMonth:
    month_obj: Month

    ...
```

Comment: 解決しました。単純なことでハマっていました。。。